# How to detect in a bash script that the parent session has finished ?

Tags: linux, bash, sleep

Let be a bash script with an infinite loop and a sleep. We start it in the background.

If the user logs out, I would like to be able to know it in the script. How can I know from within the script that the parent session has been closed ?

Comment: [`SIGHUP`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when a session is closed, SIGHUP will be sent to the processes. In Bash, you can use `trap` command to detect signals. For example, if you execute `trap exit  SIGHUP` in advance, then Bash will exit when it receives SIGHUP.